# Не работают скрипты с другого домена, при подгрузке через ajax?

Tags: ajax, javascript

При динамической ajax подгрузки дополнительной html страницы с другого домена, перестают работать скрипты. Именно когда указываю другой домен, в остальном же работает. Любые идеи?

Comment: Ссылку на страницу, которую загружаете и список подключенных у вас скриптом, пожалуйста, дайте.

Comment: вы хотите сделать кроссдоменный запрос?

Comment: Приведите код, или ждите экстрасенсов.

Answer (score 1):

ВООБЩЕ это сделать нельзя, но всё таки, [вот](http://lobach.info/develop/javascript/croossdomain-ajax-request/), почитайте: